# Conflicting Preamble

Tags: fancyhdr, subfiles

I am having an issue with my header showing up on each page (besides the chapter pages) in my document. I am including a MWE with all of the packages that I am using and wanted to see if anyone sees where the contradiction is that is causing my header and footer not to build.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[paperheight=7.5in,paperwidth=7.5in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx, amsmath, xcolor, wrapfig, float, subfiles, enumitem, xcoffins, atbegshi,fontspec, etoolbox}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\setmainfont{Futura}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\Large\bfseries}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
   \markright{\thechapter\ #1}}

\newcommand{\changefont}{%
    \fontsize{10}{9}\selectfont
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}


\definecolor{BLUE}{HTML}{23afdc}
\definecolor{RED}{HTML}{a81e2d}
\definecolor{ORANGE}{HTML}{ea6d3c}
\definecolor{YELLOW}{HTML}{e6a327}
\definecolor{GREEN}{HTML}{5fa244}
\definecolor{INDIGO}{HTML}{005988}
\definecolor{VIOLET}{HTML}{7B2C8E}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\import{titlepage/}{titlepage.tex}


\tableofcontents

\import{introduction/}{introduction.tex}

\import{overview/}{overview.tex}

\import{components/}{components.tex}

\mainmatter

\import{level1/}{level1.tex}

\import{level2/}{level2.tex}

\import{level3/}{level3.tex}

\includepdf[pages=-, addtotoc={1,section,1,0. The Fool,h0}]{0.TheFool}

\includepdf[pages=-, addtotoc={1,section,1,I. Fireyes,h1}]{I.Fireyes.pdf}


\end{document}
```

When I build my main file, I can only get the header to appear on a couple of the even pages.

When using subfile, what exactly needs to be in the preamble on the imported pages for this to work?

Each of the imported TeX files have very basic preambles and are just text files with a few images. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You have not provided an example that anyone can run to debug your problem. You are setting the header text with `\rightmark` and `\leftmark` so in book class that essentially means the text from section and chapter level headings, but it is impossible to guess what headings you have if you show no example.

Comment: Consult the documentation of the `import` and the `subfiles` package. You use the `\import` command of the `import` package. In this case, the loaded files may not contain any preamble, no `\documentclass` and no `document` environment. When using the `subfiles` package, the preamble should basically be concentrated in the main file. Do you really need `import` and `subfiles`? For most applications `\input` commands are sufficient.

Comment: @gernot I initially was using subfiles to import my TeX subfiles, but when I had to import the pdfs I switched to import. Should I distinguish between the two?

Comment: @Pyro1368 It's hard to give advice without knowing what you actually want to achieve. Use `\input` if you want to include tex code from another file as if it appeared in place of `\input`. `\import` does the same as `\input`, but additionally treats any paths in the subfiles as relative to the subfile (and not relative to the main file as `\input` does). `\subfile` does the same as `\import`, but additionally removes an initial `\documentclass...\begin{document}` as well as a trailing `\end{document}`. The latter only makes sense if you want to typeset the subfiles separately, by themselves.